# SQL Server 2008 R2 (Report Builder 3.0) - Dynamic Sub-Reports

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, subreport, reportbuilder3.0

I have a few reports that I've built in Report Builder 3.0 on SQL Server 2008 R2, what I would like to do is join these reports into a single report with dynamically generated sub-reports and pass an array of GUIDs as a parameter and then depending on the type of record the GUID represents in the database - generate the appropriate sub-report.

I know this wasn't possible in previous versions, however its been several years since I last tried and as such I'm wondering if this scenario is possible and if so are there any resources out there that touch on this subject as I'm struggling to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure your scenario is just to display one at a time. You have a main report in which you wanted a dynamic number of different subs to be displayed.

1) A main report (Main) with a tablix containing a subreport (SubMain), the dataset for Main passes id, subid and subtype. SubMain has no dataset.

2) And directly in the SubMain add all subs (SubDetail) which have their own dataset. And then set visibilty for SubDetails depending on type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this example or use drill-down sub report ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581(v=sql.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314(v=sql.105).aspx